Prove that an "interval" in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\interior}{Int}$
I'm studying Real Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and came across the following exercise. Let $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,...,b_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Let us suppose that $a_i < b_i, \forall \ i \in \{1,...,n\}.$ Show that
$$I = \{x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: a_i < x_i < b_i, \forall \ i \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$$
is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n.$
I'm not really sure if the first sentence is correct because I didn't actually prove that $I \subset \interior I$. Instead I proved the result by proving that every point in $B(x,r)$ is an interior point of $I$. However, my professor usually writes a sentence similar to the one I wrote before starting the proof.
First off, we want to prove that $\interior I = I$, i.e., $\interior I \subset I$ and $I \subset \interior I$. However, the first inclusion is rather trivial. Thus, we only need to prove that $I \subset \interior I.$
Let us fix $x \in I$. Let us consider
$$\delta_i = \min \{b_i -x_i , x_i - a_i\}, i \in \{1,...,n\},$$
and let us take $$r=\min_{1 \leq i \leq n} \delta_i.$$
We'll prove that $B(x,r) \subset I.$
Let $y \in B(x,r).$ Then,
$$\forall \ i \in \{1,...,n \}, |y_i - x_i| \leq \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i - x_i|^2 \bigg)^{1/2} = ||y-x||< r \leq \min \{b_i-x_i,x_i - a_i \} .$$
Thus,
$$y_i - x_i \leq |y_i - x_i| < b_i - x_i \Longrightarrow y_i < b_i$$
and
$$x_i - y_i \leq |y_i - x_i| < x_i - a_i \Longrightarrow y_i > a_i.$$
Therefore, $y_i  \in ]a_i,b_i[.$ This means that $y \in I.$ Given that $y$ is arbitrary, this implies that $B(x,r) \subset I$, in other words, $I$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ $\blacksquare$

So what is your question? The proof looks good.

Looks all  good I think.

@TimonKolt I'm not sure if I need to write the first sentence of my proof, because my professor usually writes it.

Thank you, @psl2Z !

On a secondary note, we usually call sets of that form (open) cubes.

@BenSteffan I didn't know that. Thank you!

@TiagoCoelho You should add this to your question, because otherwise its unclear what your question is

I will @TimonKolt

@BenSteffan, I would probably understand what you meant if you called such a set an open cube, but I'd be a bit surprised. I've never heard such a set being called a cube before - to me a "cube" is a particular three-dimensional solid with all edge lengths the same, and a "hypercube" is the higher-dimensional analogue, which is still a special case. I've more commonly heard "open (axis-aligned) box" or maybe "open (axis-aligned) hypercuboid" for sets like this.

If you prove that $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ is open set for the standard topology  on $\mathbb{R}$ then you've done because the product of $n$ copies of that interval is an open set in the product topology of $n$ copies of standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, which is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Alternatively, it’s the intersection of a finite number of open half spaces and so is open.

Answering the question: Is the following sentence really necessary/correct?
"First off, we want to prove that $\text{Int } I = I$, i.e., $\text{Int } I \subset I$ and $I \subset \text{Int } I$. However, the first inclusion is rather trivial. Thus, we only need to prove that $I \subset \text{Int } I.$ "
You want to prove that $\text{Int } I = I $, so formally yes, that is how equality of sets is defined. But as you mentioned one inclusion is rather trivial, so i assume a lot of people would just say "So we have to prove $I \subseteq \text{Int }I$, i.e. $\forall x \in I: x \in \text{Int } I$".
Note that $\text{Int } I:= \{x \in I\mid \exists \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+: B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq I\}$. So to prove the inclusion you actually have to prove:
$$\forall x \in I \exists \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+: B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq I$$
and that is exactly what you did.
Thats why i have to correct you slightly: You did show directly $I \subseteq \text{Int }I$.
Returning to the term necessarity: A lot of authors would probably just have shown the latter criteria without the sentences you have mentioned, as an complete proof. So concludingly i have to say: Its all a matter of taste/precision if this sentences are really necessary. The actual proof is what you wrote after this sentence.

I think you explained it perfectly and solved my misunderstanding. Thank you, @TimonKolt!
